# Removing index.php from URL cause 404 in yii

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, yii

## The problem

**Initial problem:**
Hi I have a newly made Yii site where I want to remove the index.php from the URL.
Example: "/index.php/site/index" should be "/site/index"

I have been using this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#hiding-x-23x guide but i only receive 404.

I hope that you are able to point a mistake or help me debug this problem!
Please let me know if I have left out any relevant information.

OBS: The "home" page works as intended, other pages are broken.

**Status of the problem:**
It seems like it is an apache/ubuntu problem with mod_rewrite.so

### Answer

After help from different people it all works now :D I had to install "rewrit" to get it running, i did that by writing 
    Running a2enmod rewrit
The below configuration of my system solved the problem for me, I hope this thread will help others in similar problems.

### My system

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)  
Server built:   Nov  8 2012 21:37:45
```

#### Apache httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/MY_SITE/FOLDER_CONTAINING_YII/">
AllowOverride All
#...
</Directory>
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

*This is the entire content of the file*

#### Apache Error Log

```
File does not exist: /.../htdocs/site, referer: http://.../htdocs/index.php/site/index
```

*I added the dots*

#### Restart Apache

```
kah@webaalborg:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2 
[Mon Nov 26 20:16:35 2012] [warn] module rewrite_module is already loaded, skipping
  ... waiting 
[Mon Nov 26 20:16:36 2012] [warn] module rewrite_module is already loaded, skipping
                                                                          [ OK ]
```

#### /ect/apache2/available-sites/default

```
...
DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/MY_SITE>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
     </Directory>
...
```

#### Yii Directory structure:

- framework
- htdocs

  - assets
  - css
  - .htaccess
  - index.php
  - index-test.php
  - themes
- protected

#### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

#### main.php config file

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'caseSensitive'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',   
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: Can you show the output of apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES here?

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633649/how-to-remove-index-php-in-yii-framework/9633842#comment17713654_9633842

Comment: This might be trivial, but have you remembered restarting apache?

Comment: @Suhoij I have added the "error" output of the dump. It seems that my system have an unforseen problem. :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Server can not find mod_rewrite.so. Looks like the problem with apache installation. Try to remove this string from config file and enable the module with a2enmod rewrite.

Comment: @suhoij When i restart the server I now get a warning that i load rewrite_module several times so that is not a problem anymore. Thanks on the tip on "a2enmod rewrite". We have eliminated some of the problem but it is still not working :S

Comment: @rasmus I wrote in the question the result of a restart.

Comment: @KimA.Jakobsen Did you remove the string LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so  from httpd.conf?

Comment: @suhoij It works now. Can you add an answer where you explain the problem with mod_rewrite.so then I will thumb it up :D

Comment: @KimA.Jakobsen I have edited my previous answer and added my comments there. Glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are working on Linux(say ubuntu) then go to the path `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` there you will find a file named as `default`,

```
    <Directory /var/www/> <--- ***root directory***
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all <---- ***change this line***
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>
```

and i think your problem will resolve.

Thanks.

Comment: After i did what @suhoij wrote i did what you suggested and it works. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you `AllowOverride` in your directory directive?

```
<Directory "/your/path">
AllowOverride All
#...
</Directory>
```

If not this would explain why your rewrite rules does not work.

Comment: I have not inserted any such code. What is my directory directive and where do i find it?

Comment: Sorry I was afk. This depends on your server configuration and on your destibution (only on linux) search for a httpd.conf or a vhost.conf.

Comment: I added it, but it did not change anything. Is there supposted to  stand anything where you wrote the "..."?. A thing i forgot to mention is that the frontpage works. I do not get any error when I write http://site.com/ when I enter other pages e.g. http://site.com/login it displays 404.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this into .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

And also remove the line 'LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so' from httpd.conf and enable the rewrite module from command line, executing a2enmod rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all <---- ***change this line***
    Order allow,deny  <---- ***change this line***
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they are not as easy to learn from as code with an explanation. Without an explanation it takes considerably more time and effort to understand what was being done, or changes made to code.  The explanation is important both for people attempting to learn from the answer and those evaluating the answer to see if it is valid, or worth up voting. Marking the lines to change is helpful, but it would be better if it was as a valid syntax comment.