# yii urlManager: if hide index.php, stop work rules

Tags: php, yii

If I hide (redirect by .htaccess or by php code) index.php name script in URL, the rules are stop working (404 errror).

It means that http://site.ru/index.php/test worked at start and http://site.ru/test isn't working now.
What I can to do?

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        'test'=>'site/index',
    ),
```

I added it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

all is fine BUT **now my 404 rule is not working...**

```
(ErrorDocument  404     /404.html)
```

**Answer**
If you dont want dinamic 404 page (default in yii site/error), then change it:

```
RewriteRule . index.php
```

to

```
RewriteRule .* /404.html
```

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542560/removing-index-php-from-url-cause-404-in-yii?rq=1

Comment: please share your redirect rules in .htaccess

Comment: now my 404 rule is not working

Answer (score 0):

The routing rule you have create in main.php is working fine, but you have not tell apache to over-ride the redirect rule from .htaccess.  If you are using linux then create a allow over-ride rule under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`

```
<Directory "/baepath/to/application">
AllowOverride All
#...
</Directory>
```

Or more often, you can create a virtual enviroment by creating a new directory rule for the project.