# Yii2+ vue project, subpages are redirected from 404

Tags: apache, vue.js, yii2, router, history

I have yii2+vue project and it works well except sub urls are first redirected from 404. 
My htaccess file looks as following:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Vue router :

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    store.dispatch('auth/check')
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            if (to.path == '/login' && res.status) {
                next('/')
            } else if (!to.meta.guest && !res.status) {
                next('/login')
            } else {
                next()

            }

        }, () => {
        })
})
```

When I access any subpage, like http://domain/subpage, it shows 404 apache page first..after that redirects to content page managed by vue.  Please help

Answer (score 0):

its apache2 + yii issue not vue js issue router . check this 
    [Removing index.php from URL cause 404 in yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542560/removing-index-php-from-url-cause-404-in-yii)

Comment: Thanks but I have AllowOverride All in place and it won't help