# How to remove index.php completely in yii when user give redirect url

Tags: .htaccess, yii, url-rewriting

I search how to remove index.php in yii.
it's working fine, but 
[How to remove index.php in Yii Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633649/how-to-remove-index-php-in-yii-framework)

protected/config/main.php

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            'redirect/<redirectUrl>'=>'site/index',
            'login'=>'site/login',
            'privacy'=>'site/privacy',
            'password'=>'site/forgot',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

my htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

when i check the following url

yii.mywebapp.com/index.php?redirecturl=http://www.google.com

it's working
but i removed index.php

yii.mywebapp.com/?redirecturl=http://www.google.com

it's also working

but i need when some user request redirect url with 
yii.someurl.com/index.php?redirecturl=someurl
i want to hide index.php in the url

please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place this rule just below your `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)index\.php([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: thanks anubhava it's working nice..once again thanks