# How to remove index.php and ?r= in Yii Framework

Tags: yii

[image: How to remove "index.php" and also wants to remove "?r=". I want to make URLs user friendly.]

How to remove "index.php" and also wants to remove "?r=". I want to make URLs user friendly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove index.php in Yii Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633649/how-to-remove-index-php-in-yii-framework)

Answer (score 2):

Do these 3 steps:

1. Enable Url re-writing on Apache.
2. Place .htaccess on root of your project

   ```
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   RewriteRule . index.php
   ```

In your configuration protected/config/main.php set showScriptName to false like this to your url manager components >> urlManager

```
'urlManager'=>array(
  'urlFormat'=>'path',
  'rules'=>array(
      '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
      '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
      '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
  ),
  'showScriptName'=>false,
)
```

Comment: If you're having trouble like I just did - make sure "AllowOverride All" is set in the appache /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file - otherwise your .htaccess file is not going to work!

Answer (score 1):

1) enable your urlManager in protected>>config>>main.php by adding these line to the array:

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
  'showScriptName'=>false,
    ),
```

2) The .htaccess file should be in the site root in the same of index.php level and should be like that:

```
    RewriteEngine on

    # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)

    # otherwise forward it to index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

3) make sure that your Apache configuration **AllowOverride All** not **None**