# How to hide index.php from url in yii framework

Tags: php, yii

Implemented my project in Yii on Apache server.It is working fine.I want to hide`index.php` in the `url` both in production and local server ,are running on Apache.

I tried with below config. 
`'show Script Name'=>false,`

but its not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633649/how-to-remove-index-php-in-yii-framework

Answer (score 1):

property "showScriptName" should be without spaces.

```
array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        ......
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName' => false
        ),
    ),
);
```

don't forget enable mod_rewrite for apache
and create .htaccess file in webroot directory with

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

also I recommend you to read this UrlManager guide: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url