# how to remove index.php from url using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii

I'm working  on yii framework and trying to remove index.php from url (httpx://localhost:801/index.php/aImages) it should be like this httpx://localhost:801/aImages . So the code  given below is in my .htaccess file. This code is working on my localhost but not my team members machine.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what is `[L]` in `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove index.php in Yii Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633649/how-to-remove-index-php-in-yii-framework)

Answer (score 4):

try :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

and in your config file, use:

```
...
'urlFormat'=>'path',
'showScriptName'=>false,
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

You can check [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/214/url-hide-index-php/) for further reference.

Comment: Thanks nana.chorage you reply was really helpful actually the rewrite_module was not working and the link you provided really helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

reference : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line should be

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to .htaccess file and add the following lines...

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php